# How to write json config so to pick an object depending on the flag value

Tags: json

```json
{
  "mapper": {
    "flag": "flag_name_whose_value_is_retrieved_from_properties_file",
    "if_flag_is_true_call_this_obj": {
      "foo": "xyz",
      "num": "123"
    },
    "if_flag_is_false_call_this_obj": {
      "foo": "abc",
      "num": "12"
    }
  }
}
```

Please do help me, how I can form the meaningful json config that reflects the same behaviour which i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

**Version 1**

```bash
jq 'if .mapper.flag == "true"
    then .mapper.if_flag_is_true_call_this_obj
    else .mapper.if_flag_is_false_call_this_obj
    end' input.json
```

**Version 2 (with defaults)**

```bash
jq 'if .mapper.flag == "true"
    then .mapper.if_flag_is_true_call_this_obj
    elif .mapper.flag == "false"
    then .mapper.if_flag_is_false_call_this_obj
    else {foo:"default", num:"default"}
    end' input.json
```

If `.mapper.flag` contains a boolean value instead of a string, you can shorten the first line to `if .mapper.flag`.

**Output for `flag: "true"`**

```json
{
  "foo": "abc",
  "num": "12"
}
```

**Output for `flag: "false"`**

```json
{
  "foo": "xyz",
  "num": "123"
}
```

**Output for `flag: "anything else"`**

```json
{
  "foo": "default",
  "num": "default"
}
```